# Binomial distribution probability of product being defective is 0.01

Tags: binomial-distribution

Q. The probability that a product is defective is 0.01. The products are packed in boxes; each box contains 10 products. A company orders a consignment of 12 boxes of products.  A purchaser randomly opens three boxes, and accepts the consignment if the 3 boxes altogether contain at most one defective product. Calculate the probability that the purchaser rejects the consignment. Round your answer to 3 decimal places.

My Sol:

I understand the distribution is binomial but I am not sure of the full solution for this. I am thinking that n=10 (each box contains 10 products) and p=0.99 (non-defective). But I am not sure how to bring in the 3 out of the 12 boxes to find the probability...any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Having "ordered" 12 boxes is irrelevant. There are millions more boxes in the warehouse. You could imagine that he "owned" all those boxes too.

So it's simply $1 - 0.99^{30} - 30 \times 0.99^{29} \times 0.01$. If you cannot use a calculator, do a Taylor expansion to get within 3 decimal points.